# I am trying to run classifier through Weka using python but I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError even though I have installed correct packages

Tags: python-3.x, weka

I have installed python-weka-wrapper3 package and I trying to create code to run Weka Classifier from python after splitting the data into train and test data. but I'm getting the error, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weka.classifiers.trees'; 'weka.classifiers' is not a package".

I am running this in a Virtual Environment. I am new to python. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
import weka.classifiers.trees as trees


def split_data():
    csv_file = r'Data_Source.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

    df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42)  # Shuffle with a fixed random seed for reproducibility

    split_ratio = 0.7

    num_rows = len(df)
    num_train_rows = int(split_ratio * num_rows)
    num_test_rows = num_rows - num_train_rows

    train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, train_size=num_train_rows, test_size=num_test_rows, random_state=42)

    return train_data, test_data

jvm.start()

num_rows, num_train_rows, num_test_rows, train_data, test_data = split_data()

classifier = trees.J48()

classifier.buildClassifier(train_data)

test_predictions = classifier.classifyInstances(test_data)

jvm.stop()
```

I have installed python-weka-wrapper3 package but I'm getting the error, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weka.classifiers.trees'; 'weka.classifiers' is not a package".

```
pip install python-weka-wrapper3
Requirement already satisfied: python-weka-wrapper3 in path\to\venv\lib\site-packages (0.2.14)
Requirement already satisfied: python-javabridge>=4.0.0 in path\to\venv\lib\site-packages  (from python-weka-wrapper3) (4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in path\to\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-weka-wrapper3) (1.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in path\to\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-weka-wrapper3) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: configurable-objects in path\to\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-weka-wrapper3) (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: simple-data-flow in path\to\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-weka-wrapper3) (0.0.1)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I am running this in a Virtual Environment. I am new to python. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

pww3 is a wrapper around Weka code running in a JVM with Weka data structure, which means that you can't use Pandas.

I recommend you having a look at the pww3 examples to get an idea on how to use the [pww3 API](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.html) (which is modeled after [Weka's](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/), but more python-like):

- https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/examples.html
- https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3-examples/

I've converted your code into valid pww3 code:

```py
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
from weka.core.classes import Random
from weka.core.converters import load_any_file
from weka.classifiers import Classifier, Evaluation

jvm.start()

# load data
csv_file = "Data_Source.csv"
data = load_any_file(csv_file, class_index="last")

# manually split the dataset
train, test = data.train_test_split(70, Random(42))

# build classifier
j48 = Classifier(classname="weka.classifiers.trees.J48", options=[])
j48.build_classifier(train)

# evaluate on test set
evl = Evaluation(test)
evl.test_model(j48, test)
print(evl.summary())
print(evl.predictions)

jvm.stop()
```